# Need to sort given strings (Strings starting with x first)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Code doesn't return last word when given `['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']` list.

```
def front_x(words):
    x_list = []
    no_x_list = []
    [x_list.append(i) for i in words if i[0] == "x"]
    [no_x_list.append(words[i2]) for i2 in range(len(words)-1) if words[i2] not in x_list]
    x_list.sort()
    no_x_list.sort()
    return x_list + no_x_list
print front_x(['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'])
```

Must be:

```
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

With lists `['bbb', 'ccc', 'axx', 'xzz', 'xaa']` and `['ccc', 'bbb', 'aaa', 'xcc', 'xaa']` everything is right `['xaa', 'xzz', 'axx', 'bbb', 'ccc']` and `['xaa', 'xcc', 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterating on `range(len(words)-1)` looks incorrect. More so, making list appends with list comprehension is quite **unpythonic**; list comps are for building lists not making making list appends which is rather *ironic* here.

You can perform the sort once by sorting based on a two-tuple whose fist item checks if a word *startswith* `'x'` and puts those ahead. The second item in the tuple applies a lexicograhical sort on the list, breaking ties:

```
def front_x(words):
    return sorted(words, key=lambda y: (not y.startswith('x'), y))

print front_x(['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'])
# ['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the -1 from `range(len(words)-1)`
This will be the minimal change in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
words = ['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark']

new_words = [i for i in words if i[0].lower() == "x"]

words = [i for i in words if i[0].lower() != "x"]

final_words = sorted(new_words)+sorted(words)

print(final_words)
```

Output:

```
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `len(words)` instead of `len(words)-1` to get expected output.

So, try this way :

```
def front_x(words):
    x_list = []
    no_x_list = []
    [x_list.append(i) for i in words if i[0] == "x"]
    [no_x_list.append(words[i2]) for i2 in range(len(words)) if words[i2] not in x_list]
    x_list.sort()
    no_x_list.sort()
    return x_list + no_x_list

print front_x(['mix', 'xyz', 'apple', 'xanadu', 'aardvark'])
```

Output :

```
['xanadu', 'xyz', 'aardvark', 'apple', 'mix']
```

Comment: That's simply a duplicate answer